# I get this error when trying to start another activity: This intent has no action set and is not explicit by component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am trying to open a new activity as follows:

`startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, ActivityLogInSignUp::class.java))`

But I get this error:

This intent has no action set and is not explicit by component.You should either make this intent explicit by component or set an action matching the targeted intent filter.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in lint version `8.2.0-alpha15` that results in a false positive warning. Creating `Intent` using class constructor will create intent with explicit component, so it is safe to use.

The bug appears to be not yet fixed as of version `8.2.0-alpha16`. As a workaround you either silence the warning or downgrade lint version by adding `android.experimental.lint.version=8.2.0-alpha14` to `gradle.properties`

Matching issue in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/294200850

Answer (score -3):

**UPDATE**

Looks like it is a bug as mentioned by `Sergei` so my solution covers a way to start an intent without showing warning messages until it gets fixed.

**SOLUTION**

According to Google:

> Intents that have no action and do not specify a component are a
> potential security risk, and using them will result in a crash in an
> upcoming version of Android.

The way to start an `explicit intent` without showing warning messages in Android Studio (open an activity from our android app) would be like so:

```
startActivity(
    Intent().setClassName(
        "com.example.myapplication",
        "com.example.myapplication.activities.login_signup.ActivityLogInSignUp"
    )
)
```

You can find your class name from the manifest for example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.login_signup.ActivityLogInSignUp"
        .
        .
        ./>
```

For `implicit intent` would be as usual:

```
val i = Intent()
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
i.setData(Uri.parse("www.example.com"))
startActivity(i)
```

Now our app is going to connect with an outside application in order to show us a website.

For more check [android intents source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)

Comment: Adding `setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)` also seems to fix the warning. Any reason why your approach is better?

Comment: `setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)` even though seems it fixes the issue, it is in not intended to open an inside activity, but to describe an action for an outside activity. The right way is the one I propose, for explicit.

Comment: If you actually take a look at the [Intent class sources](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Intent.java), specifically at constructors and `setClassName` method the you'll see that there's no difference between them